# Moving project to xcode 4 gives "Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

I upgraded to XCode 4 and one of my projects won't compile anymore. Has anyone had this problem? Full error stack below (slightly reformatted for legibility):

```
Ld /Users/stephen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/viewer-dsbfkuoythcgojfrsktxcccyfnuj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/viewer.app/viewer normal i386
cd /Users/stephen/projects/Quipper/iPhone-viewer
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 \
    -arch i386 \
    -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk \
    -L/Users/stephen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/viewer-dsbfkuoythcgojfrsktxcccyfnuj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator \
    -L/Users/stephen/projects/Quipper/iPhone-viewer/AdMob \
    "-L/Users/stephen/projects/Quipper/iPhone-viewer/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries & Headers" \
    -L/Users/stephen/projects/Quipper/iPhone-viewer/FlurryLib \
    -F/Users/stephen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/viewer-dsbfkuoythcgojfrsktxcccyfnuj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator \
    -filelist /Users/stephen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/viewer-dsbfkuoythcgojfrsktxcccyfnuj/Build/Intermediates/viewer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/viewer.build/Objects-normal/i386/viewer.LinkFileList \
    -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 \
    -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -lAdMob -framework iAd \
    -framework StoreKit -framework MediaPlayer -lOAuth -lxml2.2 \
    -framework MessageUI -framework CoreLocation -framework QuartzCore \
    -framework CoreMedia -framework AVFoundation -framework SystemConfiguration \
    -framework CoreAudio -framework AudioToolbox -framework Foundation \
    -framework UIKit -lFlurry -framework OpenAL \
    -o /Users/stephen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/viewer-dsbfkuoythcgojfrsktxcccyfnuj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/viewer.app/viewer

ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_StartChallengeViewController.user_pack_id
    in /Users/stephen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/viewer-dsbfkuoythcgojfrsktxcccyfnuj/Build/Intermediates/viewer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/viewer.build/Objects-normal/i386/StartChallengeViewController-C52C140DA244D284.o
    and /Users/stephen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/viewer-dsbfkuoythcgojfrsktxcccyfnuj/Build/Intermediates/viewer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/viewer.build/Objects-normal/i386/StartChallengeViewController-469DDEB33F89F484.o
    for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared a global iVar with an assigned value (e.g. `int i = 2;`) with the same name in 2 different classes, one of those classes being `StartChallengeViewController`. If cleaning the project (Cmd Shift K) doesn't help, try renaming one of the iVars to something else, or not giving it an initial value.

Comment: Thanks for your help, in the end it was because I had two files in the project with the same name! However, you got me looking in the right direction thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

Cleaning the project

Setting Base SDK to latest iOS
Setting Deployment Target to the iOS version you want to build for.